# 'list' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I do know it's cause that `map` is a function and not a method of list. But is there a way I can use the map function to pass data to the function called inside map.

Here's my code:

```
def func1(lines):
    global newlst
    for line in lines:
        qtype = re.search("qtype=(\S+)",str(line))  
        ......
file = sc.textFile("C:\\TestLogs\\sample.log").cache()
result = file.map(lambda x: x.split("\n")).collect()
print(type(result)) #it is a list
lines = result.map(func1).collect() #I want to pass the contents of result to func1 through map function.
```

Error:

```
    lines = result.map(func1).collect()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Is there any other way I can pass my data from `results` to `func1` but by using `map` or any concept in spark that generates an rdd?

Comment: Don't `.collect()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in you calling collect to store the result of a RDD here:

```
result = file.map(lambda x: x.split("\n")).collect()
```

This command will return to you a list, not an RDD.
If you remove the `collect()` from this row like this:

```
result = file.map(lambda x: x.split("\n"))
```

this will work.